# Updating a subdocument within another subdocument

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My app is an API build with Expressjs / Mongoose...

I have the following Schema, which I am trying to update a subdocument of a subdocument. Essentially the "phones" array, which is part of the "contacts" array, which is a subdocument of the "profile" object.

I'm trying to understand how to traverse through an object tree and update.

Here is an example schema that I'm using:

```
{
   "_id": "588b5a7d6d76c815ff6b9e7a",
   "name": "Joe Smith",
   "owner_id": "588b5a5d6d76c815ff6b9e79",
   "__v": 1,
   "contacts": [
      {
         "contact_name": "Jim Parks",
         "_id": "588b5abd6d76c815ff6b9e7c",
         "phones": []
      },
      {
         "contact_name": "Perry Mips",
         "_id": "588b5abd6d76c815ff6b31de",
         "phones": []
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried to fist narrow the search by doing a findOn() and passing the ownerId for the record. Then updating the "contacts" array in the following way:

```
router.route('/:ownerId/addphone/:contactId')
.put(function(req, res) {

  console.log('Req Body: ', req.body);
  console.log('Req: ', req.params);
  Profile.findOne({owner_id:req.params.ownerId}, function(err, profile) {

    var contacts = req.body.contacts;
    console.log('contacts', contacts);

    profile.contacts.id(req.body._id) = contacts;
    profile.save();

  });
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
    router.route('/:ownerId/addphone/:contactId')
.put(function(req, res) {

  console.log('Req Body: ', req.body);
  console.log('Req: ', req.params);
  Profile.update({owner_id:req.params.ownerId,"contacts._id":req.body._id},{phones:req.body.contacts}).exec(function(err, profile) {

    console.log(err)
    console.log(profile)

  });
});
```

I hope this helps you.!!